# Canceling or editing an edit after suggesting it in the Late Answers queue causes redirection to the answer

Tags: bug, review-queues, suggested-edits, late-answers

Canceling or editing a subsequent edit after *suggesting* one in the Late Answers review queue causes redirection to the answer, not the reviewing page for that answer.

Steps to reproduce (only users with <2K rep):

1. Open the [Late Answers review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/)
2. Click the "edit" link below an answer
3. Suggest an edit to the answer
4. Click the edit link again
5. Click "Cancel" or make additional edits and save them at the bottom of the page

GIF demonstrating issue:

[image: GIF showing issue]

Comment: This *might* also be the case in First Posts and some other queues.